# unable to locate mingw32

Tags: application-development

I'm trying to compile from source everything I need in order to build Ubuntu touch for my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4. I used to guide from the Ubuntu web site and when I enter this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip bzr curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 schedtool \
  g++-4.8-multilib

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw32
```

I have tried to enable `universe` like some sites suggest but I can't figure out how to do that. I am trying this build without any previous knowledge of what to do.

---

I'm running 15.10 I've tried going through the software center to make available universe but it's already ticked

Comment: What exactly can't you figure out? if you are using a regular desktop version of Ubuntu, you should be able to add `universe` with 2 clicks from the Software Center (Edit->Software Sources... and check the box)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? `mingw32` is only available for [14.04 and 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mingw32).

Answer (score 1):

In general you will just have to make a

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu YOURDISTRO (precise, trusty, wily etc.) main universe'
sudo apt-get update
```

inside a shell this should add the universe repo to your sources.list. You can also add the line manually to your sources.list:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(the command above actually does this)

Another oppurtunity is to go to packages.ubuntu.com and to search for the mingw32 package. Then install it manually.

The repo you need is listed there also. Here is a pointer:

[Download the mingw32 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/i386/mingw32/download)

But be aware of a possible so called "apt-hell". This happens when a certain package needs more dependencies and the next packages needs even more dependencies and the next package....you see where this leads right?

Resolving dependencies can be a great hassle.

Comment: For `main`, `universe`, etc., you don't need to use the full `deb URL release ...` command. Just `add-apt-repository universe` will do.

Comment: Nice hint, didn´t know that. thx